# Grouping in BGN

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

The below equation is mentioned in [Homomorphic Encryption and the BGN Cryptosystem](http://theory.stanford.edu/~dfreeman/cs259c-f11/lectures/bgn) (pdf, page 4):

> Mult(pk, $C_1$, $C_2$): Choose $u \xleftarrow{R} [1, n]$ and output $D = \hat{e}(C_1, C_2) \cdot e(Q, Q)^u \in \mu_n$.

I could not understand difference between $\hat{e}$ and $e$ without the hat. An explanation with examples will be appreciated.

According to paper, $\hat{e}$ is a Weil Pairing Distortion map but it does not explain $e$ without the hat. Would they both result in GT or G?

Comment: I don't know this paper, but from context clues and notation I'm guessing it's some kind of bilinear pairing operation.

Comment: It is from the BGN paper. I just updated the link

Comment: Thats not the paper, that are lecture notes. Obviously, the missing hat on the second pairing is a typo.

Comment: Sir are you sure ?

Answer (score 1):

It is just a typing error. Both have hat.